# Only One Form is visible in the panel whichever is called first

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created two forms ( Message1 and Message 2) and a Main Form. I am dynamically loading one of the Message Form on the basis of the Main Panel Combo Selection. Main Panel has a combobox with two options, 1 and 2 and an Empty Panel.
I tested this but only one Form is Visible, whichever one is selected first.

Below is the code :

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cbox = (ComboBox)sender;
            if(cbox.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                Message1 objForm = new Message1();
                objForm.TopLevel = false;
                panel1.Controls.Add(objForm);
                objForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
                objForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                objForm.Show();
                
            }
            else
            {

                if(cbox.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    Message2 objForm = new Message2();
                    objForm.TopLevel = false;
                    panel1.Controls.Add(objForm);
                    objForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
                    objForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    objForm.Show();

                }
            }
        }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Dispose of the previous form.

Comment: Do `panel1.Controls.Clear()` before new `Add`.

Comment: @Sinatr `Clear()` does not dispose.

Comment: thanks clear() works not Dispoe on panel. I have 200 such messages , do you think it will be good to add 200 such forms? I have update the code in answer

Comment: The Show method is blocking and waits for form to close before continuing.  To see both forms you have to capture the close event so form doesn't close. See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net.  You probably want to keep form visible where my code make for not visible.

Comment: @jdweng No at a time I want just one form.

Comment: @jdweng `Show()` isn't blocking anything.  With `TopLevel = false;` these forms are just glorified UserControls.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for the Answers. The clear() works.

```
public partial class MainPanel : Form
{
    Message1 objForm1;
    Message2 objForm2;
    public MainPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cbox = (ComboBox)sender;
        objForm1 = new Message1();
        objForm2 = new Message2();
        if (cbox.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            panel1.Controls.Clear();
           
            objForm1.TopLevel = false;
            panel1.Controls.Add(objForm1);
            objForm1.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            objForm1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            objForm1.Show();
            
        }
        else
        {

            if(cbox.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {

                panel1.Controls.Clear();

                objForm2.TopLevel = false;
                panel1.Controls.Add(objForm2);
                objForm2.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
                objForm2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                objForm2.Show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should move `objForm1 = new Message1();  objForm2 = new Message2();` to the form's constructor so they only get created once each, which will make the `panel1.Controls.Clear()` work correctly.  Right now, you are creating multiple forms without disposing them every time you change the combo box.

Comment: As LarsTech mentioned in comments, `.Controls.Clear()` doesn't dispose of the objects you've added to that collection (no matter what objects these are), it just remove the reference from the collection: the original object is still *alive*. Make a backwards loop and call `Dispose()` on each object, if you have more than one in there. You *clearing* the collection no matter what is selected, so do that just once. Maybe also build a *factory*, so you cal just pass the object Type you want to create. (Forms instead of UserControls, IMO, bad choice).